# Custom Lucene Sharding with Hibernate Search

Tags: lucene, sharding, hibernate-search

Has anyone experience with custom [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/) sharding / paritioning using [Hibernate Search](http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/search.html)?

The documentation of [Hibernate Search](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en/html/search-configuration.html#search-configuration-directory-sharding) says the following about Lucene Sharding :

> In some cases, it is necessary to
>   split (shard) the indexing data of a
>   given entity type into several Lucene
>   indexes. This solution is not
>   recommended unless there is a pressing
>   need because by default, searches will
>   be slower as all shards have to be
>   opened for a single search. In other
>   words don't do it until you have
>   problems :)

Has anyone implemented sharding in such a way for Hibernate Search that also queries can be target to one of the shards?

In our case we have Lucene queries that should target only one shard per query.